# How can you get Vim to wrap bulleted text with indentation?

Tags: vim

In Vim, I can type a line like this:

```
- When in the Course of human events it becomes necessary for one people
  to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another
  ...
```

and Vim will wrap the text so that it aligns to the right of the dash. But if I try this with an asterisk, this is what happens:

```
* When in the Course of human events it becomes necessary for one people
to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another
...
```

Is there a way to make the autoindent work with the leading asterisk in the same way it does for the leading dash?

Comment: What file type are you using to get hanging indent with the dash? The answer is probably buried in that syntax file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is done using the `comments` setting (see `:help 'comments'` and `:help format-comments`).

The setting you need to add is `fb:*`, which says that there is a comment type that starts with `*` and the `*` must be followed by a blank and is only on the first line of the comment.  Vim handles the rest.  However, note that default settings include `*` as the middle of a multi-line C comment, so you'll need to disable this.

If the hyphen-prefixed and asterisk-prefixed lines are the only ones you want to work like this, do this:

```
set comments=fb:-,fb:*
```

Alternatively, tweak the default comments setting as you like: `:set comments?` shows the current setting and `:help format-comments` explains what it all means.

If you want this to be specific to a file type, create a file in `~/.vim/ftplugin` (or `vimfiles` on Windows) with a filename as `extension.vim` (e.g. `txt.vim` for `.txt` files).  In this file put:

```
setlocal comments=fb:-,fb:*
```

This will configure the `comments` setting for the relevant file type without affecting other files.